# JOIN with JPA: what queries should I write to get the same result I get in JDBC?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jdbc

I'm new to JPA and I was trying to convert a method I was using in JDBC to JPA as an exercise.
This is supposed to **calculate all masses of all stars in my database and update the relative mass column**. To calculate a mass I need the temperature of a star and the value of its flux at 350um band. Problem is I have those data saved in different tables of my database, therefore I have to use a JOIN.

**JDBC APPROACH**

```
public void updateAllMasses() {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT s.starid, s.temperature, f.value" +
            " FROM star s JOIN flux f " +
            "ON s.starid = f.source " +
            "WHERE f.band = 350.00 AND f.value != 0";
    try {
        ResultSet resultSet = databaseUtilJDBC.dbExecuteQuery(selectQuery);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            String starId = resultSet.getString("starid");
            Double flux350 = resultSet.getDouble("value");
            Double temp = resultSet.getDouble("temperature");
            if (temp != 0) {
                String updateQuery = "UPDATE star " +
                        "SET mass = 0.053 * " + flux350 + " * (100) * (EXP(41.14 / " + temp + " ) - 1) "
                        + "WHERE starid = '" + starId + "';";
                databaseUtilJDBC.dbExecuteUpdate(updateQuery);
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**JPA APPROACH ATTEMPT**

Here I would need to make somehow a `JOIN` between `Star` object and `Flux` object.

Here's a draft of the `Star` class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "star")
public class Star implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "starid", nullable = false)
    private String starId;
    @Column(name = "temperature")
    private BigDecimal temperature;
    @Column(name = "mass")
    private BigDecimal mass;

    // With all constructors, getters and setters

}
```

Here's the entity class I'm using for the flux:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "flux")
public class Flux implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId private FluxId fluxId = new FluxId();
    @Column(name = "value")
    private BigDecimal value;

    // With constructors, getters and setters

}
```

With its idclass:

```
@Embeddable
public class FluxId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column(name = "source", nullable = false)
    private String source;
    @Column(name = "band", nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal band;

    // With constructors, getters and setters

}
```

Here's finally my attempt with JPA:

```
public void updateAllMasses() {
    String query = "???"; // Query to get all values I need
    List list = databaseUtilJPA.dbExecuteQuery(query);
    for (Object aList : list) {
        Star star = (Star) aList; // Here I would just get a Star object... while I would need also it's flux value at 350 band!
        if (!star.getTemperature().equals(BigDecimal.valueOf(0))) {
            query = "UPDATE Star star SET star.mass = 0.053 * flux.value * 100 * (EXP(41.14 / star.temperature) - 1)" +
                    " WHERE star.starId = '" + star.getStarId() + "'";
            databaseUtilJPA.dbExecuteUpdate(query);
        }
    }
}
```

What queries should I write?

Comment: Post the code of your entities. And don't use raw types. Generics exist in Java since Java 5, release in 2004, 13 years ago. Time to catch up.

Comment: @JBNizet added the code as you suggested :)

Comment: OK. To use joins, you need associations between entities. The source of your Flux should be of type Star, and be annotated with ManyToOne or OneToOne (depending on the cardinality). You missed the point of JPA, which is to map databases as an interconnected graph of entities: an Employee belongs to a Company, which has an Address, linked to a City, containing Districts, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is not mapped correctly. If you want to use joins from JPA you have to declare them correctly. Your FLuxId has to look like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class FluxId implements Serializable {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="source")
  private Star star;

  @Column(name = "band", nullable = false)
  private BigDecimal band;

  // With constructors, getters and setters

}
```

You then mark your Flux class as having a separate IdClass:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(FluxId.class)
public class Flux {         

  @Id
  private Source source;

  @Id
  private BigDecimal band;

 // With constructors, getters and setters

}
```

Warning it is absolutely essential that you implement a correct equals() method for it that ensures that an object after persisting it is identical with itself *and* is identical if your retrieve from the database.

Make sure it looks something like this:

```
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    if (obj == this) return true;       

    if (obj == null || !(obj.getClass().equals(this.getClass())))
        return false;

    FluxID otherFluxId = (FluxID)obj;

    if (this.getSource() == null
            || otherFluxId.getSource() == null
            || this.getBand() == null
            || otherFluxId.getBand() == null)
        return false;

    return this.getSource().equals(otherFluxId.getSource()) && 
           this.getBand().equals(otherFluxId.getBand());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {

    if (this.getSource() == null && this.getBand() == null) return super.hashCode();

    return (this.getSource() != null ? this.getSource().hashCode() : 0 ) ^
           (this.getBand() != null ? this.getBand().hashCode() : 0 );

}
```

Please note that this implementation has the flaw that hashCode() before persisting it is different than after persisting it. I don't know how to avoid this but you have to be careful if you store your entity in some collection before persisting it.

Once you have done all this your query becomes:

```
SELECT f.source.id, f.source.temperature, f.value
FROM Flux f
WHERE f.band = 350.00 AND f.value != 0
```

If you want the object you can work with the object, too:

```
SELECT f.source
FROM Flux f
WHERE f.band = 350.00 AND f.value != 0
```

(Not 100% sure about the syntax of the last one.)

Comment: Thanks for your very useful answer, I'm about to test it!
I have a question: once I execute the query and get the `List`, how do I access the results? Until now I've been used to get only objects I had already and not "custom made" for the query. (So I would have runt `list.get(index)` and cast it to the class I needed). [e.g. the equivalent of `resultSet.getBigDecimal("columnName")` in JDBC]

Comment: If you select multiple expressions in a JPQL query you will get an array of objects. If you don't want that simply return SELECT DISTINCT s. I would recommend to write a unit test to play around with JPQL queries. I don't think there are any good UI (but please let me know if you find one)

Answer (score 0):

JPA supports native JDBC queries just as well.

But if you have a `one-to-many` relationship then you could define it in `jpa` using annotations, either on your `Star` or `Flux` class or both.

```
@Entity
public class Star {
    @OneToMany
    private List<Flux> fluxes = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class Flux {
    @ManyToOne
    private Star star;
}
```

So then your query could:

```
"select star s from Star join s.fluxes f where f.band = ? and f.value <> ?"
```